# Swift cloudkit using another project database

Tags: swift, containers, cloudkit

I am trying to access a different project in my app and am having a problem with one query. This is one the same account and I am not getting any other errors? Do I need to replace this query with another one?

```
publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil , completionHandler: ({ results, error in
```

my Error is:

> Argument labels '(_:, inZoneWith:, completionHandler:)' do not match any available overloads

This is the code I'm using to set up the database and container. This project(myOldProject.OldAppName) is named differently from the App that I am currently using. I have selected this in the custom containers in the iCloud setup. All the other queries seem to be OK.

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "ICloud.MyOldProject.OldAppName")

let publicDB = CKContainer(identifier: "ICloud.MyOldProject.OldAppName")

var publicDatabase: CKDatabase?
```

Here is another way to state the problem:

**This works fine:**

```
let container = CKContainer.default()
var publicDatabase: CKDatabase?
var currentRecord: CKRecord?
let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
```

**This does not work and gives me the error!**

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "ICloud.OldProject.AppName”)
var publicDatabase: CKDatabase?
var currentRecord: CKRecord?
let publicDB = CKContainer(identifier: "ICloud.OldProject.AppName")
```

Comment: Please clarify your update. What works fine and what doesn't? What error and where?

Answer (score 2):

I got it!

let publicDB = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.Project.AppName").publicCloudDatabase

I forgot the .com in the identifier and I forgot to add .publicCloudDatabase